# Overwriting highlighted text in TeXShop

Tags: editors, texshop

I foolishly updated TeXShop recently and I now have the following problem.

Previously, I could highlight text in the editor with the cursor and start typing to overwrite it. Now if I highlight some text to replace "abc" and I start typing something that requires holding shift down, such as "$def...", I end up with "$abc$def...". In other words, the highlighted text is enclosed with $...$ and then the rest of the text is inserted directly afterwards.

How can I get back to the previous setting of simply overwriting the highlighted text?

Comment: Welcome to the site TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got to the `Editor` tab of `TeXShop->Preferences` and uncheck `Editor Can Add Brackets` at the bottom of the `Editor` section of that pane.

Comment: By the way, it has nothing to do with the Shift key but rather with delimiters that are generated in pairs when there is a selection of 3 or more characters; i.e., typing $ with that selection automatically surrounded the selection with a matching set of $.